# Instance reused between scenarios

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have class with this structure:

```
class A:

   words = {}

   def addElement(key, value):
       words({key: value})
```

Then if I do this in one test scenario:

```
a1 = A()
a1.addElement("a",1)
```

And then create a new instance in another test scenario:

```
a2 = A()
a2.addElement("b",2)
```

Then this assert fail since I have two elements.

```
assertTrue(len(len(a2.words)==1)
```

Why in the second scenario the instance that I create is the one from my previous test?

Regards.

Comment: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` is what I get from running this code. Please check your MCVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `words` is a class member, not an instance member. That means that `words` will be shared among every instance of `A`. You can turn `words` to an instance member using `self`:

```py
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.words = {}
   
   def add_element(self, key, value):
       self.words[key] = value
       
a0 = A()
a0.add_element('a', 'a1')
assert len(a0.words) == 1

a1 = A()
a1.add_element('b', 'b1')
assert len(a1.words) == 1
```

Comment: The answer is correct thanks